# Intuition around covering maps and pull backs to degenerate forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

I apologise in advance for asking what I'm sure is a very nebulous question. The specific set up is - I have $T^*\mathbb{C}\equiv\mathbb{C}^2$ with coordinates $(z,w)$ and the usual (for me) sympletic form $\omega=Re(dz\wedge d\bar{w})$ and I am looking at the pull back under a coordinate change $(z,w)=(u^2,w)$ under which the symplectic form pulls back to something which is degenerate on the hypersurface $Re(u)=\pm Im(u)$. Looking at the big picture, I find it unsurprising that the two form become non-degenerate, as $u^2$ is a branched cover but I can't see intuitively why it is along this hyper surface. I am sure this has an easy answer but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The map $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ given by $u\rightsquigarrow u^2$ is *not* a covering map. It is a branched covering, with precisely one preimage point for $0$.

Comment: How is $u$ supposed to be related to $(z,w)$?

Comment: By $z=u^2$. So I have a manifold$\mathbb{C}^2$ with coordinates $(z,w)$ equipped with the canonical symplectic form. I now wish to pull this back under the smooth map $(u,w)\mapsto(u^2,w)$ and wish to understand why the form is degenerate on (the preimage of) $Re(z)=\pm Im(z)$. I have edited the question, this wasn't clear at all, thanks!

Comment: Arrrrgh! I mean it's degenerate on $Re(u)=Im(u)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was silly in the end. The hyperplane I described is the one exactly mapped to the imaginary axis by squaring. As the symplectic form is the real part of $dz\wedge d \bar{w}$, of course when we pull back we get a degenerate form